# single sign on for asp.net and sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

I have an asp.net application which signs users in manually. The custom authentication procedure checks several data sources and finally sets a forms authentication ticket for the user, if he is successfully authenticated.

I want to share this ticket with sharepoint 2010. I will not be signing in through sharepoint, so there is no need for authentication procedure to caried out on the sharepoint side.

I have tried using claims-based authentication on the sharepoint side, but don't really know how to set it up, since I do the authentication manually on the asp.net application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endded up going with STS. Works very well. There is an MS devkit that has some templates for VS2010 that get you  going very quickly.